# Best way to update a FlatList with Redux store

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a Redux store with a nested object : [Part of the Redux store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSQ0S.png)

I'm using the first element of the array as data of my FlatList because I don't want to display all the items in once.

But if I want to add the second element of the array and update the list. What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your `data` value as a state prop and you can use `onEndReachedThreshold` to set the scroll distance from the bottom you want your `onEndReached` to be triggered. Then call your function to load more items `onEndReached`, then your FlatList will be updated.

It will looks something like this:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.listDataSource}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderListItem(item, index)}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor} // dont'forget to declare _keyExtractor
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.5} //when scroll reach half distance from bottom. Min value 0, max 1.
  onEndReached={() => this.loadMoreItems()} // this.setState({ listDataSource: newList }), for instance
/>
```

In the example above, every time the scroll reaches half the list, it will trigger the `onEndReached` function.

If you don't want to use your component state, you can also trigger an action (`this.props.loadMoreItems()`), update your reducer and use its value as `data` (`this.props.listDataSource`).

You can find more details in the official docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Soutot, thank you for the answer but I realised that my problem was badly phrased so please excuse me for that.

My problem is more related to Redux. If my store already contains all my data but i display only one part of it, let's say the first element of an array. What is the best way to display the second element with the first one. Should I take the second element in my store and concatenate it with the current data List ?